# React Native: How to disable drawer in specific screen?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I've been trying to do the navigation but I'm sticking with this problem for a while. How can I disable drawer for the screen 'work'. I know that drawer has an option 'gestureEnabled' but I've tried to put this into stack's option but it doesn't work. Or anyway that I can do the 'gestureEnabled' in the stack's option?

this is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';

import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import { createDrawerNavigator, DrawerContentScrollView, DrawerItem, DrawerItemList } from '@react-navigation/drawer';

import HomeScreen from './screens/HomeScreen'
import DocumentsScreen from './screens/DocumentsScreen'
import WorkFlowScreen from './screens/WorkFlowScreen'
import AboutScreen from './screens/AboutScreen'
import ShowAccessTokenScreen from './screens/ShowAccessTokenScreen'
import LoginScreen from './screens/LoginScreen'
import Work from './screens/Work'

import { WorkHeader } from './screens/Work'
import { HomeHeader } from './screens/HomeScreen'

//------------------------Navigation-----------------------
const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

//----------Drawer----------
function DrawerNavigator() {
    return (
        <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Home" drawerContent={props => {
            return (

                <DrawerContentScrollView {...props}>
                    <DrawerItemList {...props} />
                </DrawerContentScrollView>
            )
        }}>
            <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={StackNavigator} />
            <Drawer.Screen name="About" component={AboutScreen} />
            <Drawer.Screen name="ShowAccessTokenScreen" component={ShowAccessTokenScreen} options={{ drawerLabel: 'Your Token', gestureEnabled: false }} />
        </Drawer.Navigator>
    )
}

//-----------Tabs-----------
function TabNavigator() {
    return (
        <Tab.Navigator tabBarOptions={{
            showLabel: false,
            style: {
                position: 'absolute',
                marginHorizontal: 20
            }
        }}>
            <Tab.Screen name='HomeScreen' component={HomeScreen}
                options={{
                    tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
                        <View style={{ alignItems: 'center', }}>
                            <Icon name='home' style={{ color: focused ? `#e32f45` : `#748c94`, }} />
                            <Text style={{ color: focused ? `#e32f45` : `#748c94`, }}>HOME</Text>
                        </View>
                    ),
                }} />
            <Tab.Screen name='DocumentsScreen' component={DocumentsScreen}
                options={{
                    tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
                        <View style={{ alignItems: 'center' }}>
                            <Icon name='folder' style={{ color: focused ? `#e32f45` : `#748c94`, }} />
                            <Text style={{ color: focused ? `#e32f45` : `#748c94`, }}>DOCUMENTS</Text>
                        </View>
                    ),
                    unmountOnBlur: true,
                }} />
        </Tab.Navigator>
    )
}

//----------Stacks----------
function StackNavigator({ navigation }) {
    return (

        <Stack.Navigator >
            <Stack.Screen name='LoginScreen' component={LoginScreen}
                options={
                    {
                        headerShown: false,
                    }} />
            <Stack.Screen name='HomeScreen' component={TabNavigator}
                options={
                    {
                        headerTitle: () => <HomeHeader navigation={navigation} />,
                        headerLeft: null,
                    }} />
            <Stack.Screen name='WorkFlowScreen' component={WorkFlowScreen}
                options={{ gestureEnabled: false }} />
            <Stack.Screen name='ShowAccessTokenScreen' component={ShowAccessTokenScreen} />
            <Stack.Screen name='Work' component={Work}
                options={
                    {
                        headerTitle: () => <WorkHeader navigation={navigation} />,
                        headerLeft: null,

                    }
                } />
        </Stack.Navigator>

    )
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------
const App = () => {
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <DrawerNavigator />
        </NavigationContainer>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

})

export default App;
```

My Header

```
//Header---------
export function HomeHeader({ navigation }) {
    return (
        <View style={styles.homeHeader}>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.headerLeft} onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()} >
                <Icon name='align-left' size={25} color='black' />
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <Text style={styles.homeHeaderText}>eSigns </Text>
            <Icon size={25} name='address-card' color='black' />
        </View >
    )
}
```

Anyway I can fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All your stacks are wrapped in drawer. If you want to prevent this action on a page, you should change your routing accordingly. For example;

You should remove this field from the StackNavigator function and treat it as a separate field.

```
<Stack.Screen name='Work' component={Work}
    options={{
        headerTitle: () => <WorkHeader navigation={navigation} />,
        headerLeft: null,
    }} 
/>
```

I guess this is one of the confusing aspects of routing. Gather linked or possibly related pages into a stack, and then combine the stacks. Try to break it down according to their use. If you navigate to the Work stack in this snippet below, the drawer will not work. Because the drawer is in the other stack.

```
const App = () => {
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <RootStack.Navigator initialRouteName={'Main'}>
                <RootStack.Screen
                    name={'Main'}
                    component={DrawerNavigator}
                />

                <RootStack.Screen
                    name={'Work'}
                    component={Work}
                />
            </RootStack.Navigator>
       </NavigationContainer>
    )
}
```

As your application grows, I recommend that you create the stack elements on different pages, then export them and collect them in certain areas so that things are not difficult.

Comment: I want to do the button to toggle 'openDrawer' at the top left of the header of the stack navigation and it needs me to send the 'navigation' prop to the stack as you can see at the 'HomeScreen' stack. If I do use the stack navigator to be the parent navigation, it will not read the navigation prop. Any advice?

Comment: I updated the header component to the post.

Comment: You want to show the button in the work page and open the drawer when clicked. But you don't want it to open when scrolled?

Comment: Yes, I want the scroll and the button either.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. In the work page, I don't want any drawer navigation in that page. It just a page that show the PDF file and back button at the top left header

Comment: They should be coming in HomeHeader (props) {console.log (props)}. Could you please check? Because these are still in the drawer navigation.

Comment: Ohh, I got itititit. Sorry for making you confused with my question. I try your method and it works fine with my demand. Thank you so much❤️

Comment: I wish you good work. Please don't forget to confirm it.

Comment: Do I confirm it already? Is the green check is the confirm? sorry, I'm very new for this.

Comment: Yeap. Thanks =)